# Create HTML file code behaind

Tags: c#, html

I get some data from simple `XLS` file and i want to build a simple `HTML` file with simple `table`.
Something simple like this:

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a HTML file simply by using strings, if this is your table:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Company</th>
   <th>Contact</th>
   <th>Country</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
   <td>Maria Anders</td>
   <td>Germany</td>
 </tr>
 ...
</table>
```

You could write in C#:

```
public struct HTMLTable
{
    public string[] ColumnNames;
    public TableColumn[] ColumnValues;
    public HTMLTable(string[] columnNames, TableColumn[] columnValues)
    {
      ColumnNames = columnNames;
      ColumnValues = columnValues;
    }
}

public struct TableColumn
{
    public string[] Values;
    public TableColumn(string[] values)
    {
      Values = values;
    }
}

public static class HTMLTableGenerator
{
    public static string GenerateHTMLTable(HTMLTable Table)
    {
        StringBuilder Builder = new StringBuilder();
        Builder.Append("<table>\n <tr>\n");
        foreach (string ColumnName in Table.ColumnNames)
            Builder.Append("  <th>" + ColumnName + "</th>\n");
        Builder.Append(" </tr>\n");
        foreach (var Column in Table.ColumnValues)
        {
            Builder.Append(" <tr>\n");
            foreach (string value in Column.Values)
                Builder.Append("  <td>" + value + "</td>\n");
            Builder.Append(" </tr>\n");
        }
        Builder.Append("</table>");
        return Builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I've written this directly on the answer and it's not the best aprroach, you should also make changes (to make columnvalues match, html indentation, maybe adding CSS).

EDIT: 
This is an expample of implementation:

```
    string[] Columns = new string[] { "Company", "Contact", "Country" };
    TableColumn FirstColumn = new TableColumn(new string[] { "Alfreds Futterkiste", "Maria Anders", "Germany" });
    TableColumn[] TableColumns = new TableColumn[] { FirstColumn };
    HTMLTable Table = new HTMLTable(Columns, TableColumns);      
    string HTMLString = HTMLTableGenerator.GenerateHTMLTable(Table);
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\file.html", HTMLString);
```

This should create the first column row and save it to `C:\file.html`.

I just tested it, and it works properly.

EDIT2:

To add a link in html: `<a href="url">Name</a>`

To implement this you can change `TableColumn` to this:

```
public struct TableColumn
{   
 public Value[] Values;
 public TableColumn(Value[] values)
 {
   Values = values;
 }
}
```

And add this:

```
public struct Value
{
 public string Str;
 public bool IsURL;
 public Value(string str, bool isURL)
 {
  Str = str;
  isURL = IsURL;
 }
}
```

Then here:

```
foreach (string value in Column.Values)
       Builder.Append("  <td>" + value + "</td>\n");
```

Change it to:

```
 foreach (Value value in Column.Values)
   {
    if(value.IsURL) 
       Builder.Append("  <td><a href=" + value.Str + ">" + value.Str.SubString(0, 10) + "...</a></td>);
    else Builder.Append("  <td>" + value.Str + "</td>");
   }
```

EDIT3: To add the CSS code, save that CSS into a file, and that file into the output folder (ie: Solution\Project\bin\Debug\style.css")

Then add this function to `HTMLTableGenerator` :

```
private string GetStyle()
  => File.ReadAllText(Application.Info.StartupPath + "\\style.css");
```

And add this line at the begining of `GenerateHTMLTable()` (After Builder is created):

```
Builder.Append(GetStyle());
```

Comment: And how to save it on my machine ?

Comment: This is a string, to make a file from it `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, content);` If the answer is what you wanted click on the tick plase.

Comment: Just create HTMLTable and then call GenrateHTMLTable with the HTMLTable i created ?

Comment: I'll edit the question, change some of the code and add how  to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, is this all the HTML page or i need to add other HTML element in order to run the output file with my browser ?

Comment: If you run the HTML page it will show a pretty horrible looking table without separation lines, but it will work. If you want to change that you can add CSS to the HTML so it looks like your example.

Comment: Last question, i try to change the last column (URL) that will show the url in link for example the url http://google.com i want to become clickable Link without see the whole url which is very long in some cases,  can i have this example ?

Comment: I'll edit the answer. If that's all you needed please click on the tick, and set this question to answered

Comment: Yes i am sorry but i have last one (this time i am promise): if for example i want to use this style from here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro, is it good approach to open the created html file and append this style or again there is some solution via code behind ?

Comment: The style goes first, so you just write that in the `StringBuilder` and then the rest. I'll edit the answer, but you should try to do this by yourself first to learn faster, if you don't know how to do simple task like appending text or writing a file search how to on the internet, understand how that code works and then try to implement it, if it doesn't work then ask on a community, like this one, to explain you why It doesn't work. You questions should be something like: "I have this code but it doesn't work like I expected, why is that? Is there an alternative approach? "

Comment: @davidhol You ought to add the required tags for an HTML document, and maybe a DTD and Content-type, like `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /><title></title></head><body>[table goes here]</body></html>`.